# Read Excel and convert it into a nested dictionary

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I have an Excel file with a structure like this

```
name age status
anna 35 single
petr 27 married
```

Is there any generic way to convert such an Excel file into a nested dictionary with a structure like this

```
{'anna': {'age':35}, {'status': 'single'}},
{'petr': {'age':27}, {'status': 'married'}}
```

Should I first import an excel file and convert it into pandas dataframe and then to create a nested dictionary or does it exist a straight way of importing an excel sheet and creating such a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output you are asking for isn't a valid Python data strcture.

You can achieve something similar with [df.to_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('path/to/file')
df.set_index('name',  inplace=True)
print(df.to_dict(orient='index'))
# {'petr': {'age': 27, 'status': 'married'}, 'anna': {'age': 35, 'status': 'single'}}
```

Comment: I've edited the output, thanks. Could you please also advise me how can I access a dictionary by index? For example, I call 'petr' and it returns me {'age': 27, 'status': 'married'}?

Comment: @Ekaterina dictionaries have "keys", not "indexes". See https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: yes this I know but when running "list(d.keys())" it returns me all the keys except of 'name'